# I can't specify connection address using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013

Client has such destination address, as written below.

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/ConsoleService/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="KIRILL-PC\Кирилл" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And server has this configuration.

```
    <configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name ="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1"
               behaviorConfiguration ="ConsoleServiceMEXBehavior">
        <endpoint address ="mex"
                binding ="mexHttpBinding"
                contract ="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address =""
                  binding ="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract ="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/ConsoleService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="ConsoleServiceMEXBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Then I have tried to sent smth, program has given an error

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException

Firewall was disabled, both PC is located on the same network.

This is why I`m asking about favor to help me to solve this problem.

Comment: IF the service is on a different machine than the client, you need to put the server's machine name/ip address in place of localhost in your endpoint address.  localhost is just that - the machine the application is on.

Comment: Can you post the config of the server?

Comment: There could be a firewall that is blocking communication at the port level.

Comment: Try to get to the endpoint from your browser by typing `http://localhost:8080/ConsoleService/YourService.svc` where YourService is the name of your svc file and see if that works.

Comment: Is the client on another machine?

Comment: Yes, of course, Derek W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to access a different computer, replace

```
http://localhost:8080/ConsoleService/
```

with the network address of the other machine, e.g.

```
http://othermachine:8080/ConsoleService/
```

Make sure that port number is correct. Maybe it's port 80.

Comment: I have tried to fix the problem, but instead of that i got another problem.

    securitynegotiationexception

Comment: This may be because of `<identity>` you're using.But maybe ask a separate question as it's a different problem.